# How to detect scrollbar movement with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` which has the css property of `overflow: hidden`, but I still want to detect any scrolling movement when the mouse is hovering above the div. How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to detect wheel events or actual scrolling?

Comment: How do you scroll on an `overflow-hidden` element?

Comment: @Blender i'm try to detect scroll wheel movement when the mouse is on the div.

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom scroll effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use the `mousewheel.js` jQuery plugin that has been mentioned.

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7TeGu/19/)

The above jsFiddle is adapted from jQuery forum member [**ruiganga**](http://forum.jquery.com/user/ruiganga).

Answer (score 1):

you could use this.

```
    $('div').on('scroll',function(){
        // code here....
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work; Maybe it's because of my browser, Google Chrome 19.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "above the div" but you can use [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) handler:

```
$('div').scroll(function(){ // or $('div').bind('scroll', function(){ 
 ....
})
```

Comment: edited my question, take a look.

Comment: @think123 you have not edited the question, you have changed it.

Comment: @think123 that's because `overflow: hidden` has no `scroll` event.

Comment: no, the content exceeds the width and height of the div, but I want to be able to detect mouse wheel movements when the mouse is hovering above the div.

Comment: @think123 you can try this plugin https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel or this http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Answer (score 0):

Elements with overflow:hidden do not have scroll events because they don't have scroll bars. You need to change it to overflow: auto.

Another option would be binding it to the mousewheel event using the jQuery Mousewheel Plugin, although I'm not sure if that's what you're going for or not.